# cURL Tableau REST API - Upload a Data Source

Tags: rest, curl, tableau-api

I am trying to complete a three step process to upload a Tableau data source (Excel file) to the server using the REST API and cURL.

Tableau's help advises to Initiate Upload, Append to File Upload, then Publish.

https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_data_sources.htm#publish_data_source

With prior cURL / REST calls I have included a .xml package that contains specific info about the call. The Tableau help does not provide information about what is needed in the .xml package for the 3 steps here. Below is the cURL commands I have so far, but would appreciate additional direction on what I am missing.

Initiate Upload

```
curl -X POST -H {tableau_site}/api/3.7/sites/{site_ID}/fileUploads
```

This should output a session ID but the call is failing, stating "bad URL".

Append File to Upload

```
curl -X PUT -H {tableau_site}/api/3.7/sites/{site_ID}/{upload_session_ID}
```

Publish

```
curl -X POST -H {tableau_site}/api/3.7/sites/{site_ID}?uploadSessionId={upload_sessionID}&datasourceType=excel-direct&overwrite=true
```

I appreciate any help - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An Excel file is not a Tableau data source. A Tableau data source has metadata describing the columns and other info and references the Excel file (or database) which contains the data. A Tableau data source can be represented by an xml file with a TDS extension. You can also create a packaged data source with a TDSX extension that zips the TDS file together with a copy of the original XLSX file.

You want to publish a TDSX file, not an XLSX file

If you are using Python, this library will make using the REST API easier https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/. This example might be helpful https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/blob/master/samples/publish_datasource.py